# UITextView does not display

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview

There is a UITextView (green) inside a UIScrollView that should be displaying some text, but does not.

The frame of the ext view looks correct and has a width and height greater than 0. Any idea of what is going on?

```
"<AppName.UITextView: 0x7fd1ff810800; baseClass = UITextView; frame = (560 160; 23840 80); text = \'This text should appear\nT...\'; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600001b9a520>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000015a48c0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {23840, 48}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}>"
```

[image: Green UITextView within a UIScrollView]

Comment: can you give more information such as ViewController from where you added this text view or story board screen and autolayout constraints involved.

Comment: @regeint : The UIViewController has a UIScrollView that has constraints to fill the, the rest is all done programmatically - views are added as subviews to the scroll view without constraints after setting their frame. 

Although in the screenshot I only one text view (for confidentiality reasons), a few hundred are drawn properly and this was the only text view that was not displaying it's text properly.

See my solution/workaround below.

Answer (score 0):

What is peculiar about the UITextView is that it is very wide, over 23000 points wide. I tried a not so wide version of the same view, 500 points wide, and placed it right under the buggy view... it worked.

To solve the issue I changed the view hierarchy (UITextView within a standard UIView) so that the text views have a maximum width of 500 pts and it's working.

**Possible root cause:** The UITextView either wasn't designed to draw itself with extremely large widths or there are some technical limitations that prevent it from doing so.

[image: A not so wide UITextView does display the text]